# Using setters together with instance_variable_set

Tags: ruby, setter

I'm using this simple construct for initializing a class with a hash:

```
def initialize(params)
  params.each { |k, v| instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v) }
end
```

But instance_variable_set doesn't use the setter and so I can't handle special abilities. 
Is there an other nice way for initializing a class AND handle some extras in setter methods?

Comment: Your problem is not clear. What are the special abilities that you cannot handle?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `send` to call the setter method on `self`:

`params.each { |k, v| self.send("#{k}=", v) }`

Comment: This would work for those attributes having setter enabled. I would do `self.respond_to?("#{k}=") ? self.send("#{k}=", v) : instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v)`.

Comment: Depends on your use case obviously.

Comment: Sure, and I +1ed your answer, but the use of `instance_variable_set` in the original question suggests that OP does not expect raising exceptions on undefined accessors.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Logan's answer, you could do this to use defined setters and create accessors when not defined:

```
params.each do |name,value|
  if respond_to?("#{name}=")
    send "#{name}=", value
  else
    instance_variable_set "@#{name}",value
  end
end
```

Let me know if you have questions about the above and I can update the answer further.

*Update*

Or, as suggested by @mudasobwa, if you want there to be default accessor methods for all your instance variables, you could use this form:

```
params.each do |name,value|
  attr_accessor(name) unless respond_to?("#{name}=")
  send "#{name}=", value
end
```

Comment: Since you voluntary define accessors, why not `attr_acccessor name unless respond_to?("#{name}="); send "#{name}=", value`? Currently your answer looks a bit inconsistent to me.

Comment: @mudasobwa that's a nice abbreviation, I like it. I think the original syntax I used is probably easier for anyone who is new to these ideas to understand, but I'll update the answer to include that more stylish alternative :)

Comment: The syntax is only because comments do not let to paste snippets. My question is: why do you call `instance_variable_set` in the else branch? You already have an accessor, hence it’s logical to use it.

Comment: As mudasobwa writes, it is not about nice of not. Unless you do it like what mudasobwa points out, you lose the whole point.

Comment: @mudasobwa I meant, I agree that doing `attr_accessor unless` followed by `send` is a nicer way to write this, but I think if someone is coming to SO as a Ruby novice that will be harder to understand than the very simple `if else` form. I updated the answer to recommend your suggested form.

Comment: BTW I understand your point is, as it was originally written why define an accessor but then call instance variable set instead of using the accessor. I agree with your point, if you're going to freely define accessors just define the missing accessors first and then use the accessors for each param. I've updated the answer accordingly. Thanks @mudasobwa!